# Modify Rest POST request behavior with query String

Tags: rest

I have a resource which basically represents a number. I have two possible updates for this number: Set the number to a specific value or add a value to it. Now I'm confused if I can use the query string part of the URL to specify the desired behavior.

Something like this:

```
/resource/{id}/?mode=add
/resource/{id}/?mode=set
```

Or is there an alternative way two represent to update strategies for a rest resource? 
An Alternative would be to extend the request body with this information but this since strange, since the request data should contain the data and not "meta information" for the request itself - as far as I understand REST apis.

The project is an ordinary angularjs (client) and java (server) project.

Comment: Are talking about a design decission or a technical issue ? Can you provide some code?

Comment: This sounds like RPC. What are your resources?

Comment: The resource itself is a object with some fields and one of it is a number. Like for example you would model a library: You would have a book resource, with title, author and a quantity of how many books this library contains.

Comment: Is there a reason not to let the client decide what the new number should be, and have them just push it up through PUT, POST, or PATCH?

Comment: The operation is part of a mass update, the user updates over 200 instances of this resource in one call. The user can then decides if she wants to add a certain amount to the existing count or maybe just set the count of this resources.